# Magento 2 : Prevent "payment method" based on country ID

Tags: magento2, override-model

I have override "`Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement`" file in custom module

I want to prevent some "afterpay" payment method to be displayed for some country.

So i need to override "getPaymentInformation" method.
I have override it
& customize method

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function getPaymentInformation($cartId)
{
    $quote = $this->_quoteFactory->create()->load($cartId);
    $countryId = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getCountryId();
    $paymentMethods = $this->paymentMethodManagement->getList($cartId); 
    /** @var \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\PaymentDetailsInterface $paymentDetails */
    foreach ($paymentMethods as $method) {
        print_r($method->getCode()); echo'</br>'; //getting method code here
    }
    exit;
    $paymentDetails = $this->paymentDetailsFactory->create();
    $paymentDetails->setPaymentMethods($this->paymentMethodManagement->getList($cartId));
    $paymentDetails->setTotals($this->cartTotalsRepository->get($cartId));
    return $paymentDetails;
}
```

I am not sure how to remove "afterpay" payment object/data & pass it to `$paymentDetails->setPaymentMethods();`

I have checked further found that it ultimately fetches methods from
`Magento\Payment\Model\MethodList` & `getAvailableMethods`

May be i can customize in that method for the same requirement ?

Comment: what you want to change in this file? Add more details please.

Comment: Hello @RohanHapani, thanks for the comment.
I have added details to question, please have a look.

Comment: @RohanHapani, can you please tell me in which area i should put my di.xml override changes if i only want to exucute override file only for
"Graphql" calls ?

Comment: @RohanHapani any thoughts on this ?

Comment: for graphql : app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/graphql/di.xml

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to override any method. You can do with the use of observer.

> Step 1:- Please create events.xml file under path
> PackageName\Module\Observer\PaymentMethodAvailable

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="payment_method_is_active">
        <observer name="custom_payment" instance="PackageName\Module\Observer\PaymentMethodAvailable" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Step 2:- Create file PaymentMethodAvailable.php file under path
> PackageName/Module/Observer

```
<?php
 
namespace PackageName\Module\Observer;
 
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
 
class PaymentMethodAvailable implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $cart;

    public function __construct(
      \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart    
    ) {
        $this->cart = $cart;
    }
    /**
     * payment_method_is_active event handler.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $shippingAddress = $this->cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
        if($observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="checkmo" && isset($shippingAddress['country_id']) && $shippingAddress['country_id'] == 'ES'){
            $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
            $checkResult->setData('is_available', false); //this is disabling the payment method at checkout page
        }
    }
}
```

**In above code i have prevent "check money order" payment method for country spain. You can do it according to your payment method and country id**

Above code is tested in magento 2.4.0 and it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i am working with graphql calls, So not use this would work with that.
Can you confirm ?

Comment: Yes, it should work.

Comment: event observer calls everywhere with API as well as with Graphql

Comment: Okay & could you please tell me when this event will be executed ?

Comment: This will execute when the page load of checkout as well as when you set shipping information and click on next button on checkout page

Comment: Thankyou, for the answer.
i will check it.